# In Java LinkedList, why the "first", "last" and "size" variable are transient?

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list

In the Java LinkedList:

```
    transient int size = 0;

    /**
     * Pointer to first node.
     * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
     *            (first.prev == null && first.item != null)
     */
    transient Node<E> first;

    /**
     * Pointer to last node.
     * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
     *            (last.next == null && last.item != null)
     */
    transient Node<E> last;
```

I think transient is used to variables which should not be serialized. So why do the three variable should not be serialized?

Comment: During reconstitution those variables are initialized while the `ObjectInputStream ` is read.  See an [implementation](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/pkg/java/util/linkedlist-637be.html) see `readObject` in "bloch code"!

Comment: LinkedList provide its own method for serializing and de-serializing.  When serializing, it only writes the size, and the values of the list.  When deserializing, it reads the size, then build the list from scratch, each node for each value at a time.  If the author did not provide their own read and write methods, then they would need to make size, first, and last non-transient.  They would also need to make the Node class serializable.

Answer (score -3):

those are just pointers to specific list elements. Only the entire list should be serialized. Those pointers will be populated upon class instantiation.
Why is this an issue for you?